# How to write a panic! like macro in Rust?

Tags: rust

For fatal error handling, I'm using the `panic!` macro, but I would prefer to have a macro that did not print the file/line information, only the error message.

I read [the macro documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/macros.html), but my understanding is a bit shaky.

I looked at the source of the `panic!` macro, but it's calling functions to do its work where the file and line information is an integral part of the operation, so I can't just tweak that.

I looked at the `println!` macro, which looks more promising, but I have two problems I an unaware of how to solve.

```
macro_rules! die {
    () => (print!("\n"));
    ($fmt:expr) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\n")));
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\n"), $($arg)*); exit(-1));
}
```

If I put the `exit()` call in, as I have on the last line, I get syntax errors when trying to call it.

If I remove the `exit()`, I don't get complaints about the macro, but this code fails to compile:

```
let file = match File::open(&path) {
    Err(why) => die!("Couldn't open {}: {}", display, why.description()),
    Ok(file) => file,
};
```

Whereas it does compile when `die!` is replaced with `panic!`.  I assume there is some magic about `panic!` which tells the compiler that it never returns?

Comment: *I get syntax errors when trying to call it* — too bad you don't **show** any of those errors. *this code fails to compile* — too bad you don't **show** how it fails.

Comment: I second @Shepmaster, please provide a [MCVE], I had to guess what types/traits to bring in, switch to `path` instead of `display`, etc... to get your examples to compile after the fix.

Comment: Yep, and the *first* error I saw is that `exit` isn't in scope, so now I had to guess if OP had their own `exit` or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, if I put the `exit()` call in, as I have on the last line, I get syntax errors when trying to call it.

That is because a macro should expand to a single item, and here it expands to two. You can simply wrap the invocation in a block `{}` and it'll just work... once you qualify the call to `exit`.

```
({ print!(concat!($fmt, "\n"), $($arg)*); std::process::exit(-1) });
```

> If I remove the `exit()`, I don't get complaints about the macro, but this code fails to compile. Whereas it does compile when `die` is replaced with `panic`. I assume there is some magic about `panic` which tells the compiler that it never returns?

It's not so much magic as the `!` type. The `panic` and `exit` functions both return `!` which is a type with no value: it cannot ever be constructed.

This is sufficient for the compiler to know that those functions will never return (they diverge), so from the point of view of type-checking, `!` is considered a subtype of all types and does not cause issues.