# Can I override a macro from the standard library with my own custom macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm working on a procedural macro, and I found that compiler does not give information about proc-macro crates when the procedural macro panics. I tried to override `panic!` to print a location:

```
macro_rules! std_panic {
    ($($args:tt)+) => {{
        panic!($($args)*);
    }};
}

/// panic! with location reporting.
macro_rules! panic {
    ($($args:tt)+) => {{
        std_panic!("{}\n --> {}:{}:{}", format_args!($($args)*), file!(), line!(), column!());
    }};
}
```

But the compiler fails with

```
error: recursion limit reached while expanding the macro `std_panic`
  --> src/lib.rs:30:9
   |
30 |         std_panic!("{}\n --> {}:{}:{}", format_args!($($args)*), file!(), line!(), column!());
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   | 
54 |                         _ => unimplemented!("handling tuple struct"),
in this macro invocation
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="131072"]` attribute to your crate
```

I set the limit to `65536` to prove that this is related to recursive expansion.

According to [the macros chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*, first edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html#scoping-and-macro-importexport), my own `panic!` is not visible to `std_panic!`, so it should use `panic!` from the standard library.

I also tried

```
#![feature(no_std)]
#![no_std]
#[macro_use(panic)]
extern crate std;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: @kennytm Thank you. But it says same thing.. and `

// Visible here: `m1`.

macro_rules! m3 // Visible here: `m1`, `m3`. ` means `panic!` should not be visible from `std_panic!` (Edit: Fixed typo. I expected enter to be <br>)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, you can override a macro from the standard library:

```
macro_rules! panic {
    ($($arg:tt),*) => {};
}

fn main() {
    panic!("Exit");
    println!("Or not...");
}
```

**No**, you cannot then call the macro you just shadowed.

Macros are expanded at the site of use. In your example, when you try to use `panic!`, it expands to `std_panic!` which in turn expands to `panic!`. At that point, your *own* `panic!` is the one in scope.

This simpler example shows that a macro calls whatever `do_foo` happens to be in scope *where the macro is expanded*. Note that there isn't even a `do_foo` defined where the macro is:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {
        do_foo()
    };
}

fn main() {
    {
        fn do_foo() {
            println!("1")
        }
        foo!();
    }
    {
        fn do_foo() {
            println!("2")
        }
        foo!();
    }
}
```

Instead, you will need to refer to the original macro via its complete path (available since [Rust 1.30](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1300-2018-10-25)):

```
macro_rules! panic {
    ($($args:tt)+) => {{
        std::panic!("{}\n --> {}:{}:{}", format_args!($($args)*), file!(), line!(), column!());
    }};
}
```

See also:

- [How to write a panic! like macro in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43254340/155423)
- [Is it possible to change the whole panic message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45053381/155423)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. I changed name of macro to fail, and overrided `unreachble!` and `unimplemented!`. I'm satisfied with this. Visibility is caculated from site of use, after expanding. It makes sense